# Android TTS: Improve voice quality or better free alternatives

Tags: android, kotlin, text-to-speech, voice

My app uses TTS to read texts, currently using default tts settings, without any customization, and the process works good, but the voice not only doesn't sound natural, but also if you listen to it carefully you will notice it a little bit robotic.

I know this is what you can expect of a free "service", but I thought that maybe you can configure it to sound more natural, or maybe there is a free Android tts library/engine I don't know already.

This is my relevant code I use to init tts and read text:

```
override fun startActivity() {
    ttobj = TextToSpeech(this, this)
}

override fun onInit(status: Int) {
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        ttsStatus = 0
        Companion.ttobj = ttobj
        val result = ttobj.setLanguage(Locale.US)
        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS","The Language not supported!")
        }

        ttobj.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(object : UtteranceProgressListener() {
            override fun onStart(utteranceId: String) {
                ttsSpeechStarted()
            }

            override fun onDone(utteranceId: String) {
                runOnUiThread {
                    ttsSpeechFinished()
                }
            }

            @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java",
                ReplaceWith("Log.i(\"TextToSpeech\", \"On Error\")", "android.util.Log")
            )
            override fun onError(utteranceId: String) {
                Log.i("TextToSpeech", "On Error")
            }
        })
    }
}

fun readParagraph(){
    if (ttsStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
        ttobj.speak(paragraph, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null,"")
    }
}
```

I was googling and found that "Speechify" has a free limited version, but was not able to find a library/gradle plugin to use it.

I've also come across "Murf", but it's not free.

Any other alternatives or any way to improve default Android's tts voice?